# TypeError using QTScript on C++ application

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtscript

I'm trying to implement the possibility to script an existing QT application.

It works fine, but some function of my class return a TypeError.

Myclass.h (really simplified) :

```
class Myclass: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public slots:
  int firstfunction() const;
  int secondfunction() const;

private:
  int m_firstResult;
  int m_secondResult;
}
```

Myclass.cpp :

```
int Myclass::firstfunction() const
{
  return m_firstResult;
}

int Myclass::secondfunction() const
{
  return m_secondResult;
}
```

The main :

```
Myclass qtObjectClass();
QScriptEngine scriptEngine;

QScriptValue qValue= scriptEngine.newQObject(&qtObjectClass);
Q_ASSERT (qtObjectClass.isQObject());

scriptEngine.globalObject().setProperty("QTscriptEngine", qValue);

QFile file("testScript.js");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QScriptValue result = scriptEngine.evaluate(file.readAll());

if(result.toString() != "undefined")
  std::cout << result.toString().toStdString() << std::endl;

file.close();

if (scriptEngine.hasUncaughtException()) 
{
  int lineNo = scriptEngine.uncaughtExceptionLineNumber();
  printf("lineNo : %i", lineNo);
}
```

The script :

```
print(QTscriptEngine.firstfunction());

print(QTscriptEngine.secondfunction());
```

And the (strange) result :

```
5
TypeError: Result of expression 'QTscriptEngine.secondfunction' [1] is not a function.
```

Where 5 is the result of firstfunction() and [1] the result of secondfunction().

Of course, the result of my function is not a function, it's pretty normal, no ?

I don't understand why one is working when the other one is not (but evaluated because [1] is clearly the good returned value of secondfunction())

(I have really simplify all the code, and maybe the problem come from an other place, but it's clearly strange)

Any idea ? 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the code you have posted, to use anything from a `QObject` in a script, the meta-object system needs to be aware of it.  That means in your example the methods must be declared as `slots` or `Q_INVOKABLE` to be called.  Also what is `QTscriptEngine`?  As `QScriptEngine` does have `firstfunction()` and `secondfunction()` as methods.

Comment: The Q_OBJECT macro defined that the functions of my class are Q_INVOKABLE, no ? And my slots are declared in 'public slots:'.
I've added my main in order to add a better understanding of my app and what is QTScriptEngine

Comment: No the `Q_OBJECT` macro does not define all methods as `Q_INVOKABLE`, but I missed your `slots` declaration, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was stupid.
I had properties defined like that :

```
Q_PROPERTY(int m_firstResult READ firstfunction)
```

The function who are in a Q_PROPERTY return a TypeError.
And I havn't even put my properties in my question, so no one was able to answer my question, sorry for that.